# Android screen size qualifier for 7" tablet

Tags: android, layout, tablet, screen-size

I'm creating an app for both phones and tablets on Android 4. I have made different layouts for phones and tablets using size qualifiers. In my res folder, I have four layout folders:

- layout-land
- layout-port
- layout-sw600dp-land
- layout-sw600dp-port

When I test this on a 10" tablet, it works fine. On a 7" tablet with a screen size of 1028x600, however, it doesn't work, it used the phone layout. I have changed the minimum size from 600 to 500, without any effect. I have checked the available screen size, like this:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    Log.d("Display height",Integer.toString(metrics.heightPixels));
    Log.d("Display width",Integer.toString(metrics.widthPixels));
```

The smallest screen size is 600 indeed, but for some reason it doesn't switch to the tablet layout. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `layout-swxxxdp` identifiers are available starting with 3.2. For versions below this you use `layout-large`, `layout-xlarge`.

Comment: That looks correct. What tablet are you testing on, and is it indeed running android 4+?

Comment: `heightPixels` and `widthPixels` are in pixels. The `600` in `layout-sw600dp` is a value in density-independent pixels. Pixels and density-independent pixels are not the same thing, and they will only be numerically equal for `-mdpi` devices.